# Display images from source directory selected by user

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a Qt application where user selects source directory which has images (.pgm files) (any number). In the UI, 
I have created a display area (QGroupBox) which has 2 QGraphicsview which displays 2 images at a time.

UI image:

[image: current GUI]

Going ahead, 
I want to create QGraphicsViews Widget for all the images and display 2 of them at a time. There will be a scroll bar to the right. 
When user drags the scroll bar down other QGraphicsView Widgets
should be visible to the user with different images. How can i do this using Qt in C++?

PS: I am able to display two images in the display area using QGraphicsView Widget when the load images button is clicked.

```
#include "ui_DataViewerPage.h"

#include <iostream>

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QThread>
#include <QSettings>

#include "DataWorker.h"

namespace Ui
{
    class DataViewerPage;
}
 // This is the main UI thread header and cpp file
class DataViewerPage : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    DataViewerPage(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~DataViewerPage();

public slots:
    void on_loadButton_clicked();

    void startWorker();
    void stopWorker();

    void displayImage(QString fileName);
signals:
    void startLoadingImages();

private:
    Ui::DataViewerPage* ui;
    DataWorker* worker;
    QSettings settings;

    // Worker thread handles data processing away from ui thread
    QThread workerThread;
    QSharedPointer<QGraphicsScene> ptr_scene;
    QSharedPointer<QGraphicsScene> ptr_scene2;
    int currentDisplayNum;
};

#include "DataViewerPage.h"

DataViewerPage::DataViewerPage(QWidget* parent)
    : QWidget(parent), worker(nullptr), ui(new Ui::DataViewerPage)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->Display->setVisible(true);
    ptr_scene = QSharedPointer<QGraphicsScene>(new QGraphicsScene(this));
    ptr_scene2 = QSharedPointer<QGraphicsScene>(new QGraphicsScene(this));
}

DataViewerPage::~DataViewerPage()
{
    workerThread.quit();
    workerThread.wait();
    workerThread.terminate();
    if (worker)
    {
        delete worker;
    }

    delete ui;
}

void DataViewerPage::on_loadButton_clicked()
{
    ui->Display->setVisible(true);
    ui->loadButton->setDisabled(true);
    emit startLoadingImages();
}


void DataViewerPage::stopWorker()
{
    workerThread.quit();
    workerThread.wait();
    workerThread.terminate();

    if (worker)
    {
        delete worker;
        worker = nullptr;
    }
}

void DataViewerPage::startWorker()
{
    stopWorker();
    worker = new DataWorker();
    worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);

    connect(this, &DataViewerPage::startLoadingImages, worker, &DataWorker::startLoadingImages);
    connect(worker, &DataWorker::displayImage, this, &DataViewerPage::displayImage);

    workerThread.start();
    currentDisplayNum = 0;
}

void DataViewerPage::displayImage(QString fileName)
{
    QPixmap pixelMap(fileName.toStdString().c_str()); // <- path to image file
    switch (currentDisplayNum)
    {
    case 0:
        ptr_scene->addPixmap(pixelMap);
        ui->img1->setScene(ptr_scene.get());
        break;
    case 1:
        ptr_scene2->addPixmap(pixelMap);
        ui->img2->setScene(ptr_scene2.get());
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    currentDisplayNum++;
}

// This is the worker thread header and cpp file. 
#pragma once
#include <QThread>
#include <QSettings>
#include <filesystem>

class DataWorker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    DataWorker();
    ~DataWorker();

public slots:
    void startLoadingImages();
signals:
    void displayImage(QString fileName);

private:
    QSettings settings;
    std::string path;
};

#include "DataWorker.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <QImage>

DataWorker::DataWorker()
{
    path = settings.value("dataDir").toString().toStdString();
}

DataWorker::~DataWorker()
{
}

void DataWorker::startLoadingImages()
{
    std::cout << "startloadingImages called..." << std::endl;
    int iCount = 0;
    for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path))
    {
        QString imgPath = QString::fromStdString(entry.path().string());
        emit displayImage(imgPath);
        iCount++;
        if(iCount > 1)
            break; // Right now do it for two only.......
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using [`QScrollArea`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html) instead of `QGroupBox`

Comment: Replacing QGroupBox with QScrollArea did not work. What I am looking for is that when the folder will have more than two images, i want to create QGraphicsView for each image and then add it inside my GroupBox or ScrollArea and there will be a scroll bar in the right side for user to drag and see rest of the images